# Debugging tf frame with multiple parents

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is usually a combination of 2 problems

- Multiple nodes to be publishing a transform of a frame (i.e. nodeA publishes `/map -> /odom` and nodeB publishes `/map -> /odom`) (EDIT: Turns out this is not an error)
- Multiple parent frames are published for the same child frame (something publishes `/map -> /odom` while something else publishes `/world -> /odom`)

It seems that the [usual methods](https://wiki.ros.org/tf/Debugging%20tools) for debugging tf tree don't help in this situation.  Is there any way to help isolate this problem?

In particular, how would one go about finding which is the offending node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341845/debugging-tf-frame-with-multiple-parents/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe `roswtf` has a tf plugin which checks -- among other things -- *reparenting* of frames.

Link to the ROS wiki: [wiki/tf: roswtf plugin](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#roswtf_plugin):

> `roswtf` `tf` comes with a plugin for [roswtf](http://wiki.ros.org/roswtf) that automatically runs whenever you run `roswtf`. This plugin will analyze your current tf configuration and attempt to find common problems. To run, just invoke `roswtf` normally:

> ```
> $ roswtf
> ```

Which would seem to be what you are asking.

The wiki page doesn't explain *what* actually is checked, but from [the code](https://github.com/ros/geometry/blob/f91b5efc160c40b6d45081fa4a5afc6b829e2059/tf/src/tf/tfwtf.py):

- time deltas ("Received out-of-date/future transforms")
- reparenting of frames
- cycle detection
- multiple authority  (this would help with multiple broadcasters sending out the same frames)
- "no msgs" (ie: are there any TF messages being published)
- unnormalised quaternions

Link to the various error / warning messages: [here](https://github.com/ros/geometry/blob/f91b5efc160c40b6d45081fa4a5afc6b829e2059/tf/src/tf/tfwtf.py#L149-L158).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-17**:
And `roswtf` may not mean what you think it does: #q277428 (and #q285116, a bit).

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-01-17**:
huh, good to know :-)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-17**:
Happened to remember using it some time (a long time) ago.

I feel `roswtf` doesn't get the love/attention it deserves. It's saved me quite a few times.